# How can I redirect a user back from a page with no html/view?

Tags: javascript, json, sinatra, http-redirect

I am doing a challenge, which uses Sinatra and Javascript and a JSON file as the database (of sorts) and have hit a roadblock that has been driving me nuts for two days. The issue is that I want to be able to be able to keep the user on the same page as the form `/homepage` (or redirect them back automatically) upon a successful submission and notify them of the successful submission from there. What actually happens is that once I submit the form, the user is redirected to the `(POST) '/'` route (and stays there) - however there is no view associated with that endpoint. What is being displayed is a server-side message.

Here is the config.ru:

```
##QUERY THE USERS LIST
get "/" do
  protected!
  File.open("./test-users.json").read
end

##ADD A NEW USER
post "/" do
  protected!
  param :name, String, required: true
  param :email, String, required: true, format: /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/

  contents = File.open("./test-users.json").read
  parsed_contents = JSON.parse(contents)
  File.delete("./test-users.json")
  parsed_contents["guests"] << {"email" => params["email"], "name" => params["name"]}
  File.open("./test-users.json", "w+") do |f|
    f.puts JSON.pretty_generate(parsed_contents)
  end

  "#{params['name']} now signed up with #{params['email']}"
end
```

Now, I am NOT allowed to modify that file or (this would be much easier!). And here is my form:

```
  <div class="sidebar-left col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <form action="/" method="POST" id="registrantForm">
      <h1>Please Register</h1>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="register-name" placeholder="username" required>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="register-email" placeholder="email" required>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      <div id="form-error" class="error"></div> 
    </form>
  </div>
```

Here are some things I have tried,

- detecting the current window.location and if it is `'/'` then redirecting back. This does not work since once you are on the `'/'` route - you are no longer on an html page so the javascript does not work.
- toying around with onbeforeunload, but this does not work because I do not have access to the destination route, and realized that even if I did, I would be thwarting the submission if I redirect away from `'/'` before the submission is complete.
- pulling the submission of the form out of the html and into JS to try to control the route after the submission(using the onload event), however I have not been able to get the data to post either sending the params as query string or a stringified object:

:

```
function submit(emailInput, nameInput){
  var params = {
    email: emailInput,
    name: nameInput
  };
  request.open("POST", "http://localhost:9292", true);
  request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
  request.onload(function(){
    window.location.assign('http://localhost:9292/homepage');
  });
}
```

or not sending params with the `request.send()`, as it seems to be grabbing it from the url's search query anyways. Both result in the page reloading on submission without a redirect to `'\'`, but without the data being saved either.

How do I go about redirecting the user back to the `/homepage` route while successfully submitting the form data? Is this possible in this set-up?

Comment: So you are not allowed to change the ruby code at all?

Comment: no. Can't change that code per the directions. I now think it was an oversight in failing to redirect from the server file, and I turned in the challenge already with two versions - one where I did not redirect I just left it in there and worked around it, another that I did add a redirect to the file. but under those circumstances - could I have redirected somehow from the client side?

Comment: Probably the simplest way to doing this is to replace the form action with js and just submit the values with js - so then no redirect happens

Comment: i tried that, it wouldn't submit. maybe because i wasn't sending the params correctly. IDK. It seems they were coming from the url's query string...but it didn't work - so i recreated the query string, and sent it. no luck. i sent them as an object, both JSONstringified and as a regular object, no luck. The data was to be submitted to a JSON file (that was acting as a DB). Ultimately i did two versions, one where i redirected server-side (in case it was an oversight on their part) and one where I did not, just dealt with the redirect. Didn't pass the challenge :(

Comment: under 'things i tried' i actually stated that I tried all of that ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Probably the simplest way to doing this is to replace the form action with js and just submit the values with js - so then no redirect happens

And that's exactly how it works. So I build some example code to prove it and explain it. (hint: I used jQuery just for convenient you can do this in plain js)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        // submit the from values with js 
        // and clean the input fields 
        // but not submit the form normally
        // that's why false is returned
        $('form').submit(function() {
            // get your form data in a standard URL-encoded notation
            // standard URL-encoded notation
            var data = $('form').serialize();

            // post your data with ajax to the server
            // https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
            // here you would add your on success function
            // to display a message to the user or whatever else
            $.post('/', data);

            // retuning false here prevents the form to get posted
            // https://api.jquery.com/submit/
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Side-note the ruby code has much potential to be better.